# How to remove spaces from numbers using dataExporter?

Tags: primefaces, apache-poi

I have many datatables (used as custom tag) in my application and all of them can be exported into one Excel file using the dataExporter function. My problem is, that the columns which are containing numbers are formatted on the frontend (like: 124 284,4) and if they are exported into Excel, they can't be handled (for examle summarize) as numbers. So... how can I remove spaces only from these columns, which contains only numbers in postProcess function? Is this even possible?

I found this postProcessor function, but this is converting EVERYTHING, not only the numeric rows:

```
public void postProcessXLS(Object document) {

        HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook) document;
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow header = sheet.getRow(0);

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        if (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            rowIterator.next();
        }

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if (cell.getColumnIndex() > 1) {
                    if (!cell.getStringCellValue().isEmpty()) {
                        cell.setCellValue(Double.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue().replace("'", "")));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my dataExporter button:

```
            <h:commandLink style="float:right">
                <p:graphicImage name="/images/excel.png" width="24"/>
                <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="#{id}" fileName="list" />
            </h:commandLink>
```

Expected result: for example 98 923,5 will be exported as 98923,5 in the Excel. All other strings will be untouched.

Comment: Then do it only for the columns you need. And if you have them as numbers in your objects that back the datatable, I'm almost 100% sure the values are stored as numbers.

Comment: This is new to me, how can I do the "only for the columns you need"? The datatable is used on at least 30 tables, how can I filter these columns out?

Comment: There is a column index in the code.

Comment: the column index is different on every table, as I said this is working on 30 different dataTables with different columns

Answer (score 2):

Best option would include extending `org.primefaces.component.export.ExcelExporter` and overriding the `exportValue` method to apply your customization. There you have full access to the output components. Provide your custom exporter extension instance to `p:dataExporter` [`customExporter`](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/dataexporter?id=attributes) attribute.

An example might look like this:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink title="hejjj!">
        Export to XLS
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" customExporter="#{myBean.customExporter}"
            target="tbl" fileName="anyFilename" />
    </h:commandLink>

    <p:dataTable id="tbl" value="#{myBean.rows}" var="row">
        <p:column headerText="Formatted Numbers with Spaces">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.number}">
                <f:converter .../>
                <f:attribute name="isFormattedNumber" value="1" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Note the `<f:attribute name="isFormattedNumber" value="1" />` added to the `h:outputText` which will help distinct the component while exporting using the `CustomExcelExporter` below:

```
package my.package;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.component.export.ExcelExporter;

public class CustomExcelExporter extends ExcelExporter {

    @Override
    protected String exportValue(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
        String exportedValue = super.exportValue(context, component);
        if (component.getAttributes().containsKey("isFormattedNumber")) {
            return exportedValue.replace(" ", "");
        } else {
            return exportedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

MyBean just to show where the exporte is created:

```
package my.package;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.component.export.Exporter;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {
    private Exporter customExporter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        customExporter = new CustomExcelExporter();
    }
    /** getters, setters */
}
```

Another option would be to try the [custom export](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/dataexporter?id=custom-export)  functionality by adding the custom [`exportFunction`](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/column?id=attributes) attribute to all the columns in question.

Comment: I think on my p:column the <f:convertNumber/> messing up the numbers on export. It's very good on the UI, but not on the export side. Is it possible to NOT converting the numbers if I push the export button?

Comment: @VORiAND I don't know how this would be possible - but I updated my answer to give a Detail on customExporter implementation.

Comment: What do I need to do to be able to use the customExporter parameter on the p:dataExporter? It says to me: "The attribute customExporter is not defined in the component dataExporter" :(

Comment: Primefaces 7.0, I'm not sure if it was available in earlier versions.